# Subquery returned more than 1 value. SQL server

Tags: sql, sql-server

i am getting following error

> Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.

below is my query i just want to add `PrePmt_Amount` from table `sales header` with `Amount` column from `sales line` and store the result in column `testing` in Table `sales header`
note- `sales header.No_` is the primary key similarly for `sales line.[Document No_]`

Query=>

```
update sales_header 
set testing  =
    (select sales_header.PrePmt_Amount + sales_line.amount 
    from sales_header,sales_line 
    where sales_header.No_ = sales_line.[Document No_])
```

Comment: The `SELECT` statement is returning more than 1 row

Comment: Can you show some sample input data and the desired result? Also, don't use `mysql` tags when your question is about SQL-Server.

Comment: How else could we explain it to you???  The error message is already pretty clear, your `SELECT` is returning more than 1 row!!!\

Answer (score 1):

I think you intend:

```
update sales_header
    set testing = (PrePmt_Amount +
                   (select sum(sl.amount)
                    from sales_line
                    where sales_header.No_ = sl.[Document No_]
                   )
                  );
```

Comment: I tried using your query but still i'm getting the same error

Comment: @Puneeth . . . This query *cannot* return that error.  The subquery has an aggregation function with no `group by`, to it always returns exactly one row.  Perhaps you have a trigger on the table that is returning the error.

Answer (score 1):

Your `SELECT` statement is returning more than one record, that means that there is more than one record in `sales_header`, `sales_line` that matches your `WHERE` clause `sales_header.No_ = sales_line.[Document No_]`

Comment: Yes but can you suggest any other way of achieving this using query.

Comment: I can, but it would likely lead to you having bad data. Can you provide some sample data from the tables? This may help us identify your problem.